# How to read / write in application

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to make a small application where when a player clicks a button it gets the values from a file, and then adds to it if the bank number is in the file and if not, makes a new bank number with the amount with it:

```
package application;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;


public class Main extends Application {
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
                try {
                        //BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
                        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Root.fxml"));
                        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
                        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                        primaryStage.show();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                launch(args);
        }
        @FXML
        private TextField banknumber;

        @FXML
        private TextField original;

        @FXML
        private TextField deposited;

        @FXML
        private TextField output;
        @FXML
        protected void onClick(ActionEvent event) throws FileNotFoundException{
                PrintStream diskWriter = new PrintStream(new File("accounts.txt"));
                Scanner diskReader = new Scanner(new File("accounts.txt"));
                int origbal;
                int addtobal = Integer.parseInt(deposited.getText());
                String number = banknumber.getText();
                if(diskReader.next().equals(number)){
                        origbal = diskReader.nextInt();
                        int newbal = origbal+addtobal;
                        diskWriter.println("Number: " + number + " Total: " + newbal);
                }
                else{
                        origbal = Integer.parseInt(original.getText());
                        int newbal = origbal+addtobal;
                        diskWriter.println("Number: " + number + " Total: " + newbal);
                }
                int newbal = origbal+addtobal;
                output.setText("You have added $" + addtobal + " to bank number: " + number + "for a total of $" + newbal);
                diskWriter.close();
        }
}
```

I am getting an error though and I don't know what is wrong with it (The line numbers match up with the paste bin):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at application.Main.onClick(Main.java:54)
        ... 54 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The file name you are using in the code is "accounts", not "accounts.txt". Also, I don't see a button being defined.

**After fixing the path name**

Now the Scanner complains (in line 54) that `next()` is called although there is no next token to be scanned. Normally, one calls `hasNext()? and proceeds only if this returns true.

*However*, the idea of writing a file and reading from it before writing has been completed (i.e., close() has been called) is a no-no.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve with your code, so I can't really suggest an improvement.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RzcxMH1u Okay, I got rid of the error, but how would I get the number value from the accounts.txt? (Not the bank number, the account balance)

Comment: This is still reading and writing from and to the same file at the same time? Don't do it. What *are* you trying to implement? Banking - not even Home Banking - doesn't work like that.

Comment: I was just trying to make a way to store a value with a name in a file, and banking was the first thing that came to mind. How would I change my current code so that it read's the file first and then writes to it?

Comment: Up front, ead **all** of the file (into a suitable Collection (or Map), close it. After running your app (deposits, withdrawals, new customers,...) before termination, write the Collection (or Map) to that file. Whether or not you write the file also after updates (so as not to lose any data in case of a crash or power failure) depends on how serious you take matters ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `java.util.properties` which loads properties from a file into a HashMap and allows you to pull values.

Assuming "accounts.txt" is of form

`banknumber1=origbal1
banknumber2=origbal2`

```
    @FXML
    protected void onClick(ActionEvent event) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Properties p = new Properties();
        InputStream is = new InputStream("accounts.txt");

        p.load(is);
        is.close();

        String number = banknumber.getText();
        String origbal = p.getProperty(number);
        int addtobal = Integer.parseInt(deposited.getText());

        if (origbal != null)
            p.setProperty(number, Integer.parseInt(origbal) + addtobal);

        OutputStream os = new OutputStream("accounts.txt");
        p.store(os);
        os.close();
    }
```